# Can i make a scatter plot with string labels by matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, string, plot, character, scatter

I have 2D array of integers which represents something like a heatmap. I want to print it as scatter plot with dots of different sizes.

Example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
test_data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=500, size=(10, 10))

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=test_data[x, y])
plt.show()
```

Result looks like this:
[Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eL1y.png)

*Is there any way how to **change range and labels of axis x and y?** I want to change them into strings.*

I want to make a plot looks like this: [Better scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81BrP.png) *(image was edited in gimp)

I tried to do it by `plt.xlim()` and also I tried to change data source to arrays of characters, but no success.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `plt.xticks` and `plt.yticks`

for example:

```
   x_ticks = ['a','b','c'...etc.]
   plt.xticks(x, x_ticks)
```

That should allow you to match the edited plot that you included.